# Removing subscript/superscript from whitespace

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm aiming to remove subscript or superscript formatting from spaces.

When I run the below code, only the top function works, while the lower function fails to do anything. If I switch the positions of the functions, still only the top function works. The functions are almost identical and I don't know where to start with fixing this. Please could someone point me in the right direction?

```
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range

'For subscripted spaces

Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
With oRng.Find
 .ClearFormatting
 .Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Forward = True
.Text = "[A-z0-9] "
.Replacement.Text = ""
.MatchWholeWord = False
    While .Execute
        If oRng.Characters(2).Font.Subscript = True Then
        oRng.Characters(2).Font.Subscript = False
        End If
    oRng.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Wend
End With

'For superscripted spaces

 Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
With oRng.Find
 .ClearFormatting
 .Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Forward = True
.Text = "[A-z0-9] "
.Replacement.Text = ""
.MatchWholeWord = False
    While .Execute
        If oRng.Characters(2).Font.Superscript = True Then
        oRng.Characters(2).Font.Superscript = False
        End If
    oRng.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Wend
End With
```

Comment: Welcome... looks like you are working with a range `oRng` but resetting the selection...

Comment: Your code is incomplete, which makes it impossible for us to discover exactly *how* it's failing. According to site policy, a [mcve] should be provided. In this case, specifically, everything to do with setting and handling `oRng` would be relevant.

Comment: Apologies for that Cindy. I have edited the text to clarify the definition of oRng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, by the time you've finished processing whichever series you put first, the range defined by Rng has collapsed to the last Found instance. Regardless, you don't need a loop. Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = " "
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .Font.Superscript = True
    .Replacement.Font.Superscript = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Font.Subscript = True
    .Replacement.Font.Subscript = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```